# Try to install bootstrap on shopify theme

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, sass, themes, shopify

I'm new to learn Coding and Absolute Beginner.

I'm trying to learn Shopify Theme Dev, so I have this sample code for installing bootstrap on folder src to scss  and then try to import bootstrap on my file app.scss here my code on app.scss

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

and here,I receive on terminal the following error:

error  in ./src/scss/app.scss

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │ @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  /Users/meganicon/meganicondev/src/scss/app.scss 2:9  root stylesheet

 @ ./src/scss/app.scss 2:14-253

  Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
/app.js  339 KiB    /app  [emitted]  /app

ERROR in ./src/scss/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │ @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  /Users/meganicon/meganicondev/src/scss/app.scss 2:9  root stylesheet
    at /Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
    at /Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:73:7
    at Function.call$2 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:88191:16)
    at _render_closure1.call$2 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:77610:12)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26152:18)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26156:19)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24600:19)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24897:40)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4311:88)
    at _Future._completeError$2 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24725:9)
    at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24117:12)
    at Object._asyncRethrow (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4065:17)
    at /Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:14087:20
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4090:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24138:12)
    at _awaitOnObject_closure0.call$2 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24130:25)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26152:18)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26156:19)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24600:19)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24897:40)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4311:88)
    at _Future._completeError$2 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24725:9)
    at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24117:12)
    at Object._asyncRethrow (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4065:17)
    at /Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:16672:20
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4090:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24138:12)
    at _awaitOnObject_closure0.call$2 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24130:25)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26152:18)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26156:19)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24600:19)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24897:40)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (/Users/meganicon/meganicondev/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4311:88)
 @ ./src/scss/app.scss

ERROR in ./src/scss/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!./src/scss/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │ @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  /Users/meganicon/meganicondev/src/scss/app.scss 2:9  root stylesheet
 @ ./src/scss/app.scss 2:14-253
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you that bootstrap scss file can't be found. You need to install it by typing the following command in a shell:

`npm install bootstrap`